# How can I stop Steam In-Home Streaming from muting my audio?

Tags: steam, steam-in-home-streaming

When I start In-Home Streaming from my Steam Link to my PC, the audio in my PC gets muted.  This is a problem because I use wireless headphones connected to my PC for the audio.  Every time I start streaming, I need to walk across the house and re-enable the audio.

Is there some way to prevent the sound from being muted in the first place?

Comment: You can also just unmute the audio by going into desktop mode

Comment: @KevinvanderVelden: Er, is there a way to do that that without being at the computer (and also without closing out of Big Picture Mode)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can unmute the windows sound from desktop mode while streaming, this can be done from the steam link.

You can enter the desktop mode while streaming with the following buttons:

[image: Power icon]
[image: Minimize Big Picture]

After that you'll get dumped into a stream of your desktop. If you have multiple monitors it'll show the one your mouse cursor is on. If you're using a steam controller it will switch to the desktop profile.

Then in desktop mode just unmute via the default method, after you're done open up steam, it'll be in regular mode but you can re-activate big picture mode and the steam link will resume streaming in big picture mode.

[image: Big picture icon]

Comment: This worked.  I need to use the left-stick to move the mouse and R2 to left-click.  Thanks!